# How to deactivate all firebase users without logged in?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

- I have a try to deactivate account from firebase, But I have faced a
  scenario like if I want to deactivate account in firebase at time I
  have to logged in with that use.
- But if I am admin and I want to
  deactivate other user account than how can I logged in with that
  user,it's seems like manual process to logged in than deactivate
  account.

1) I also have question if this overcome from triggering cloud function like when in firebase database->user(child node)->"isuser_deactivate -> yes/no" than trigger cloud function without logged in.

2) Any of api functionality that overcome that problem so please give me
    reference.

Comment: I didn't clearly understand what you are trying to achieve, but it can probably be done using the new cloud functions & their "admin" package. here is an example of removing users, should be pretty similar in your usecase https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron

Comment: @BenYitzhaki : Thnk you for reply . My question . Suppose i am admin and i want to deactivate/active some of user account without logged with that user.So how can i achieve this functionality. Because i can not insist user to deactivate/active your account

Comment: look at the "disabled" prop in the user. might be what you are looking for https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user

Comment: Thnk you for reference. But i want to re clarify my scenario to make sure you are understand my concern or not. So , i have design a admin panel in php side . In that page i have call firebase user listing with radio button for active and deactivate . Now i want to deactivate/activate reflection in firebase authentication table .

Comment: To disable a user account, you'll need to use the Admin SDK (available for Node.js and Java) on a trusted environment. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user

Comment: You could also set or clear an 'enabled' flag in their users node that, based on a rule, would not allow them to access certain data if the flag is false. So they would log in, but the app code would immediately check that flag and notify the user their account has been disabled (or whatever). So their Firebase account would technically be active but they couldn't use the app. Just a thought.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this , as you said by using a child isuser_deactivate : yes/no.

The problem you are facing is you have written rules such that  only repective users can access their childs.

```
".read" : "$uid === auth.uid",
".write" : "$uid === auth.uid"
```

change this rules to

```
".read" : "$uid === auth.uid || $uid === adminUID",
".write" : "$uid === auth.uid || $uid === adminUID"
```

Now you will be able to access their tree from you custom admin panel

Comment: I have design a admin panel in php side . In that page i have call firebase user listing with radio button for active and deactivate . Now i want to deactivate/activate reflection in firebase authentication table . \

Comment: you can set an onclick function in a radio button containing a value "yes or No" and firebase function to write in that user tree isuser_deactivate : yes /No, if you changed the rules as above you will be permitted to access the user tree, so when admin clicks the radio button for enabled or disabled, Onclick function triggers, and the value gets updated.

Comment: So as per my understanding by your answer that if i changed the rule than i can access Authentication table of firebase right?

Comment: Yeah you are right. Currently you have set the rule such that only that particular user can access. If you changed like above, it will work fine

Comment: Have you any reference function for php that can change user status in authentication table?

Comment: you can write a function using JS for firebase access which will be triggered by onclick